# Some questions about hustle and hurry from a song

Tags: word-difference, lyrics, redundancy, attributives

I was listening to a old song, but I found that some of the words in the lyrics made me confused.
Here is the sentence:

> I was never in love, never had the time in my hustle and hurry world.

Question 1, the meanings of the words, hustle and hurry are almost the same, 
am I right? When I am writing, is it grammatical to use the words with equivalent meanings in the same sentence?
If it is grammatical, what is this kind of grammar called?

Question 2, both hustle and hurry are not adjective in the above given sentence, but in my opinion, they are describing and emphasizing the word, world. Isn't it strange? or just I am thinking it too much?

Comment: You're thinking about this too much. I often sigh when I see questions about grammar based on the lyrics of songs. Generally speaking, songwriters are more interested in rhythm, rhyme, alliteration, and syllable counts than they are in grammar. As a result, you can expect to see things that you probably wouldn't find in, say, a scientific paper.

Comment: To tag on to J.R.'s comment, note how well the phrase "hustle and hurry" fits into the meter and rhythm of that stanza of the song.  Lyrically, English can sound *percussive* in song -- the words are like the beat of a drum, to match with or offer counterpoint to the actual drumbeat.

Comment: We could even say "in my hurry-up world", where "hurry up" is an imperative verb phrase used adjectivally; it would be a world in which the command "hurry up" is often heard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Repetition of sense for emphasis or ornament is quite common in popular genres, and at one time was admired even in very formal registers: consider *cease and desist* and *full and complete* in legal use, or Claudius' *disjoint and out of frame*.

   It is particularly felicitous and memorable when it incorporates alliteration or rhyme: *tried and true*, for instance, or with nouns *time and tide*, where *time* and *tide* originally had the same meaning. And both words in your example have rhyming pairs:

   - hurry and scurry
   - hustle and bustle
2. It is quite common to employ nouns as modifiers: consider *business manager* or *steel mill*; and there's no reason such *attributive* nouns can't be conjoined, particularly if they have a "collocational" meaning:

   - a bed and breakfast establishment
   - property and casualty insurance